# Set Title Color is not working - UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have created the array of UIButtons , having the same action,
if i click the first button, the first button Colour should be change, other button Colour should not be changed. how to achieve this?

```
for(titleStr in titleArray){
        
        actionButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]; 
        [actionButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        actionButton.tag = count;
        [actionButton setTitle:titleArray[count] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[actionButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [actionButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];//[UIColor greenColor]]; // AJS 3.3 change
        CGSize expectedTitleSize = [actionButton.titleLabel sizeThatFits:maximumLabelSize];
        CGRect buttonframe;
        buttonframe=CGRectMake(contentOffset,0, expectedTitleSize.width+5.0, expectedTitleSize.height+25);
        actionButton.frame = buttonframe;
        [titlewidthArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:expectedTitleSize.width]];
        [contentoffsetArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:contentOffset+3.0]];
        if(count==0){
            actionButton.titleLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Medium" size:15.0];
            [actionButton setSelected:YES];
            tempObj = actionButton;
        }else {
            actionButton.titleLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Medium" size:15.0];
            
        }
        [titleScrollView addSubview:actionButton];
        contentOffset += actionButton.frame.size.width+5.0;
        titleScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(contentOffset, titleScrollView.frame.size.height);
        // Increase the count value
        count++;
        
    }

-(void)buttonTapped:(id)sender { 

if([sender tag]==0){ 
UIButton *tappedButton = (UIButton *)sender; 

[actionButton setTitleColor:[UIColor yellowColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
actionButton.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; 

[actionButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateDisabled]; 
[tappedButton setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];    
} 
}
```

Thanks advance

Comment: can you show the code

Comment: @anbu : do u have any idea

Comment: in which button you wnat to change the color

Comment: if i click the button1, button1 color shoule be white, and the remaining button color should be default color.

Comment: try `btn.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];`

Comment: @NewbieiOS - are you tried the answer

Answer (score 0):

for that you have to take one extra UIButton Object in you header file.

While user click on any button you have to store that selected Button in refbutton object and use like below.

```
@interface YourViewController () 
{
 UIButton *btnSelected;
}
```

Now Move to your Button Action:

```
-(IBAction)buttonTapped:(UIButton *)sender { 

    if(_btnSelected){
      _btnSelected.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor]; 
    }
   _btnSelected = sender;

  sender.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; 
}
```

Hope this will help you.